# got an error "thread.cs not found" after update of visual studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have developed a windows application, before 2 days it was working smoothly.
But, yesterday I updated a visual studio 2012 via "Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Updates".
And now I am not able to run my application.
Whenever I am trying to run an application, I got an error given below.
What can I do in this situation?
[image]

Comment: Evidentially an exception was thrown, you need to set breakpoints and step through your code. Is it a Bcl extention?

Comment: You should show us some code.I don't think the problem is in `Thread.cs`, but somewhere in your code

Comment: @Codexer I have already set a startup form. But, before page_load event  occurs of that form, I got an exception.

Comment: @Pikoh Yeah, I agree, problem could be in my code also. But code of which form? How can I identify problematic form. Bcoz there are many forms.

Comment: Are you using any COM dll?

Comment: I don't know much more about COM dll. But I used a third party dll called iTextSharp for creating a pdf document.

Comment: and one more thing is whenever I try to run the application, a dialogue box opens with the title of "Find Source: appdomain.cs" and I think it's try to finding the file with name and file type of "appdomain.cs". What does it mean?

Comment: I closed that project and open a new project from scratch. But still I am facing the same error described above ("Find Source: appdomain.cs"). As far as I can guess is it should not happen if I start a new project from scratch. Problem should be with vs2017 after update. Can anyone help me to resolve this?